# Ionic datetime design issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

When I Create a blank ionic project and use ion-datetime it appears like this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwLo8.png
But When I Create a tabs ionic project and use ion-datetime it appears like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lKlP.png
so what is the problem in the blank project please ?

Comment: What does `ionic info` tell you?

Comment: in blank project you are using ionic 6+, in tabs you are using <5 . check your ionic version in both projects.

Comment: ok now how can i solve this issue in blank project ?